# vlookup with dynamic lookup_value using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to using the dynamic lookup value, I tried following the piece of advice from How to perform an excel vlookup with dynamic lookup_value using VBA? to fetch a value dynamically from another workbook.

This below code throws `#Name?` error.

Request your help to resolve the error.

**Code Excerpt**:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dynamic_lookup_value As Range
Dim LocationRef As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("XYZ")

Set dynamic_lookup_value = ws.Cells(2, 1)

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="dynamic_lookup_value", RefersTo:=Worksheets("XYZ").Cells(2, 1)

Set LocationRef = ws.Cells(2, ActiveColumn)

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & dynamic_lookup_value.Address(0, 0) & ",'[ABC.xlsx]XYZ'!C1:C26,MATCH(""Location Description"",'[ABC.xlsx]XYZ'!R1C1:R1C26,0),)," & LocationRef.Address(0, 0) & ")"
```

After execution, the formula appears as

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('A2','[HC report.xlsx]HC Report'!$A:$Z,MATCH("Location Description",'[HC report.xlsx]HC Report'!$A$1:$Z$1,0),),'G2')
```

Please note lookup value appears 'A2'(with single codes). Tried to declare the `dynamic_lookup_value` using the following piece of code but in vain.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="dynamic_lookup_value", RefersTo:=Worksheets("XYZ").Cells(2, 1)
```

If I manually remove the Singe code before and after the A2 and G2, then the formula works fine.

Request the experts advise to resolve this issue.

Many thanks,
Prabhu

Comment: The single quotes are because you are not specifying RC notation when you use the Address property.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I managed to resolve the issue per your advise.

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:**
Having been able to replicate you error, I think I have a solution: Replace your `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` with `ActiveCell.Formula`. This solved it in my simple re-creation of the problem (using the immediate-window)

This works (sets a reference to cell A1 in cell A2, based on address of Cell A1:
 `Cells(2,2).Formula = "="&Cells(1,1).Address(0,0)`

While this doesn't work (gives same issue with 'A1' in single quotes as you had): `Cells(2,2).FormulaR1C1 = "="&Cells(1,1).Address(0,0)`

Comment: Many thanks for your response Prebsus. Tried to add indirect to the formula, still the same issue.

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue now - please see my updated answer above

Comment: Many thanks for your response Prebsus. I tried to replace with Activecell.formulaR1C1 still the same issue. I'm trying to filldown the formula till certain amount of rows below. Appreciate your suggestions to resolve the issue.

Comment: I found out the issue with my macro, as advised i replaced Activecell.FormulaR1C1 with Activecell.Formula and also replaced the R1C1 reference with the formula with absolute cell reference, then macro executed perfectly. New code below:

Comment: ColumnNumber1 = AssociateIDColumnNo
    
    ColumnNumber2 = LocationDescColumnNo

    'Convert To Column Letter
    ColumnLetter1 = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber1).Address, "$")(1)
    ColumnLetter2 = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber2).Address, "$")(1) 
 ActiveCell.Formula = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & ColumnLetter1 & "2,'[XYZ.xlsx]ABC Report'!$A$1:$Z$500000,MATCH(""Location Description"",'[XYZ.xlsx]ABC'!$A$1:$Z$1,0),)," & ColumnLetter2 & "2)"

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be some confusion between named ranges and range variables in VBA. However, one problem in your formula is an inconsistent application or RC notation so you need

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & dynamic_lookup_value.Address(0, 0, xlR1C1) & ",XYZ!C1:C26,MATCH(""Location Description"",XYZ!R1C1:R1C26,0),)," & LocationRef.Address(0, 0, xlR1C1) & ")"
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Per your suggestion, I managed to resolve the issue.